# How to replace a class by using javascript when multiple classes present

Tags: javascript

Um using this Javascript to replace a specific class conditionally ,but I found out that it is cascading . How to remove a class and add a class by only using javascript and to make it work on IE8?

```
            "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
            "var elem = document.getElementById('manage-footer');" +
            "elem.onclick = function() { " +
                "if (hasClass(elem, 'footer-expand')) {" +
                "   elem.className.replace(/(?:^|s)footer-expand(?!S)/g , '');" +
                "   elem.className = elem.className + ' footer-diminish';" +
                "} else if (hasClass(elem, 'footer-diminish')) {" +
                "   elem.className.replace(//(?:^|s)footer-diminish(?!S)/g, '');" +
                "   elem.className = elem.className + ' footer-expand';" +
                "}" +
                "" +
                "" +
            "};" +

            "function hasClass(element, cls) {" +
                "return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;"     +
            "}" +
```

Comment: @RobG I only need to change a one class out of two so toggling wont help I Guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you've found a suitable *hasClass* function, so now you need some helpers that can be used to create a *swapClass* function. :-)

```
// If element doesn't have className, add it
function addClass(element, className) {
  if (!hasClass(element, className)) {
    element.className = trim(element.className + ' ' + className);
  }
}

// If element has className, remove it
function removeClass(element, className) {
  if (hasClass(element, className)) {
    element.className = trim((' ' + element.className + ' ').split(' ' + className + ' ').join(' '));
  }
}

// Remove leading and trainling white space and replace multiple spaces with single
function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/\s+/g,' ').replace(/^\s|\s$/g,'');
}

// If element has cName0, replace it with cName1
// Otherwise, remove cName1 and add cName0
// If element has neither, cName0 is added
function swapClasses(element, cName0, cName1) {

  if (hasClass(element, cName0)) {
    removeClass(element, cName0);
    addClass(element, cName1);

  // Do else whether it has cName1 or not
  } else {
    removeClass(element, cName1);
    addClass(element, cName0);
  }
}
```